# is null row allowed in json

Tags: json, loops, python-2.7

I have a json:

```
[
{ "firstName":"John" , "lastName":"Doe" },
{ "firstName":"Anna" , "lastName":"Smith" },
{ "firstName":"Peter" , "lastName": "Jones" }
]
```

I know setting values with `null` is simply accepted:

```
[
{ "firstName":"John" , "lastName":null},
{ "firstName":"Anna" , "lastName":null },
{ "firstName":"Peter" , "lastName": null }
]
```

But i wonder if there's an option of null/empty row. Like

```
[
{ "firstName":"John" , "lastName":"Doe" },
null,
{ "firstName":"Anna" , "lastName":"Smith" },
null,
{ "firstName":"Peter" , "lastName": "Jones" },
null
]
```

Though I don't know that whether an empty row is allowed in JSON format or not, I just want to, if it's allowed, then how to iterate that json object. Without having a null row is simple to iterate in any language, but what if we have null row?

The main purpose of asking this null row thing is: I'm converting the JSON into HTML tables and HTML tables do contain empty rows. **[json2html](http://json2html.herokuapp.com)**

Answer in JS/Javascript would also be accepted though I'm working on python

Comment: Interesting Question. Though I wonder in which scenario it actually makes sense to have null rows.

Comment: Actually I came across many JSON files which contain null rows, and as I mentioned I have been developing JSON to HTML conversion webapp, I wanna know if null rows are actually accepted so that I would add its support too in my webapp though I have added the support for null values.

Comment: I don't question that it exists. I'm just wondering, why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, mixed types are allowed in JSON lists. Here's some python proof:

```
>>> import json
>>> data = json.loads("""[
    { "firstName":"John" , "lastName":"Doe" },
    null,
    { "firstName":"Anna" , "lastName":"Smith" },
    null,
    { "firstName":"Peter" , "lastName": "Jones" },
    null
]""")
[{u'lastName': u'Doe', u'firstName': u'John'}, None, {u'lastName': u'Smith', u'firstName': u'Anna'}, None, {u'lastName': u'Jones', u'firstName': u'Peter'}, None]
```

In this example, You've created a JSON Array containing mixed types of rows, which is allowed. The first entry is a JSON Object, followed by a None, followed by another JSON Object, and so on.

Update: Here's how you can iterate over this list while handling the `None` entries

```
>>> for result in data:
...     # Here, we get either a dictionary or a `None`
...     if result:  # Filter out the `None` rows. You could also do a isinstance(result, (dict)) if you're paranoid
...         for key, value in result.iteritems():
...             print key, value

lastName Doe
firstName John
lastName Smith
firstName Anna
lastName Jones
firstName Peter
```

Comment: Thanks @VooDooNOFX, can you please tell how to iterate over(for loop as key-value) this json to extract data. I mean I try to iterate but due to `null` as a row it throws exception. What's the way to handle that `null row` ?

Comment: @softvar: see the edit for how to iterate the collection properly.

Answer (score 1):

In [jsonlint](http://pro.jsonlint.com/) the following JSON is a valid one. So I think null is allowed.

```
[
    {
        "firstName": "John",
        "lastName": "Doe"
    },
    null,
    {
        "firstName": "Anna",
        "lastName": "Smith"
    },
    null,
    {
        "firstName": "Peter",
        "lastName": "Jones"
    },
    null
]
```

But following JSON is not valid

```
[
    {
        "firstName": "John",
        "lastName": "Doe"
    },
    null,
    {
        "firstName": "Anna",
        "lastName": "Smith"
    },
    null,
    {
        "firstName": "Peter",
        "lastName": "Jones"
    },
    {
        null: null
    },
    null
]
```

The error is

```
Parse error on line 16:
...   },    {        null: null    },  
---------------------^
Expecting 'STRING', '}'
```

Comment: So you mean `null` row is allowed in Pure `JSON` ?

Comment: I think it is "null as a row is allowed"

Comment: How to iterate over such JSON which contains `null as a row`? I'm facing problems because of this in - `for key, value in obj` stuff